# How to mask rows of a 2D numpy matrix by values in 1D list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masking

I have a 2D numpy array that looks like this:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

And a 1D list that looks like this:

```
b = [4, 3, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'd like to mask my 2D array (a) according to which values in a given row are less than the corresponding value in my 1D list (b). For example, row a[0] would be masked according to which values in that row are less than the value at b[0]; the same with row a[1] and the value at b[1], and so on...

What I hope to get is a 2D array of booleans:

```
mask_bools = [[True, True, True, True, False],
              [True, True, True, False, False],
              [True, True, False, False, False],
              [True, True, True, False, False],
              [True, True, True, True, False]]
```

I have a silly way to achieve this with a loop:

```
mask_bools = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    mask_bools.append(np.ma.masked_less(a[i], b[i]).mask)
mask_bools = np.array(mask_bools)
```

But I feel like there *must* be a better/faster way to do this that takes better advantage of numpy functionality. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#broadcasting) less than:

```
a < b[:, None]
```

```
[[ True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False]]
```

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])

b = np.array([4, 3, 2, 3, 4])

c = a < b[:, None]

# Test equality with expected output
mask_bools = np.array([[True, True, True, True, False],
                       [True, True, True, False, False],
                       [True, True, False, False, False],
                       [True, True, True, False, False],
                       [True, True, True, True, False]])

print((c == mask_bools).all().all())  # True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])


b = np.array([[4, 3, 2, 3, 4],]*len(a)).T

a < b

array([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False]])
```

---

for more efficiency use:

```
b = np.tile(np.array([[4, 3, 2, 3, 4]]).transpose(), (1, len(a)))
```

which is harder to read however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to achieve this. Make a function that compares the values at the appropriate index and returns a boolean.

It would essentially do the same thing as you have now, but as you said, this would just be the NumPy implementation.